# Instantiation Object with method of SuperClass

Tags: java, spring

I'm developping a JAVA EE project with Spring Framework. I read a tutorial on how wa can use a SupperClass with  @MappedSuperclass annotation.

The classes are as follow:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class AbstractEntity implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
protected Long id;

@Version
protected Long version;

@Override
 public int hashCode() {
 int hash = 0;
 hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
 return hash;
 }

//initialisation
public AbstractEntity build(Long id,Long version){
    this.id=id;
    this.version=version;
    return this;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object entity){
    String class1= this.getClass().getName();

    String class2=entity.getClass().getName();
    if(!class2.equals(class1)){
        return false;
    }

    AbstractEntity other= (AbstractEntity) entity;
    return this.id == other.id;
}
```

}

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class Personne extends AbstractEntity {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Column(length = 5)
private String titre;
@Column(length=20)
private String nom;
@Column(length=20)
private String prenom;

public Personne(String titre, String nom, String prenom) {
    super();
    this.titre = titre;
    this.nom = nom;
    this.prenom = prenom;
}

public Personne() {
}

//ToString
public String toString(){
    return String.format("Personne[%s, %s, %s, %s]",id,version,titre,nom,prenom);
}

public String getTitre() {
    return titre;
}

public void setTitre(String titre) {
    this.titre = titre;
}

public String getNom() {
    return nom;
}

public void setNom(String nom) {
    this.nom = nom;
}

public String getPrenom() {
    return prenom;
}

public void setPrenom(String prenom) {
    this.prenom = prenom;
}
```

}

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "medecins")
public class Medecin extends Personne {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public Medecin(){

}

public Medecin(String titre, String nom, String prenom) {
    super(titre, nom, prenom);
}
```

}

What i didn't understand is this instatiation of Medecin Object:

```
     Medecin m=new Medecin("Mr","Paul","Tatou").build(10,1);
```

As AbstratcEntity is a super Class having the build method , how can we instatiate a child object like that, isn't contradictory with polymorphism principle?

Comment: why would it be? the child classes inherit thee build method.

Comment: Yes, they inherit the method, but the return value of build method is "AbstractEntity" , so how can we instantiate a child class from a parent one, polymorphism says the inverse no?

Comment: just think about this: Object o = "clearly a String"; String d = (String)o;

Comment: aaah ok, so i have to cast Medecin like this:                                       Medecin m=(Medecin) new Medecin("Mr","Paul","Tatou").build(10L,1L);

Comment: That's ok thank you!!!!!